# Python 3 - Mac OS X 10.6.x - How to capture microphone input raw sample data?

Tags: python, macos, capture, microphone

Greetings to all of you and thank you in advance.

I am currently doing some preliminary research on capturing microphone input data using Python 3.  Are there any currently developed libraries/modules that can support this?  I reviewed PyAudio, but it apparently is not being further developed.

My use-case for this is to build a morse code decoder to be used with existing receivers plugged in via the microphone input jack of my MacBook Pro.

I do not need any sample code, just a little nudge in the right direction.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

73

Julio Jimenez
KK4EQP

Answer (score 1):

A great audio library for Python is Gstreamer. Here's a question that will help you with microphone input: [How to fix Gstreamer to capture microphone audio and buffer or dump as raw file, when i am talking it does not save anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403339/how-to-fix-gstreamer-to-capture-microphone-audio-and-buffer-or-dump-as-raw-file)

I do not believe that there are Python 3 Gstreamer bindings, though. You will either have to swtich to Python 2, or modify the existing bindings yourself to get them working with Python 3.